# ¿ Como desinstalar IIS de Windows Server 2012 R2, para volver a instalarlo?

Tags: visual-studio, windows, iis, windows-server-2012, windows-server

Tengo un problema con IIS ya que me sale un error con un  mensaje del modulo WebSocketModule Código de error 0x80070490 cuando lo llamo desde localhost para probar su funcionamiento.

He comprobado que el rol del IIS "Protocole WebSocket" aparece como instalado pero al buscarlo en la herramienta IIS dentro en el panel central y editor configuración no aparece system.webServer/websocket.

He intentado desinstalar IIS quitando el rol para volverlo a instalar. Desde el administrador del servidor "Quitar roles y funciones" pero cuando reinicio el sistema me sale el siguiente mensaje "No puedo terminar de instalar las funciones Cancelar cambios No apague la computadora" y por lo tanto el IIS me sigue instalado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalmente el código de error que tienes es por un problema en registro de llave o instalación de componentes de windows después de una actualización.

Yo en tu caso, removería todo el rol IIS, buscaría todas las actualizaciones pendientes, reiniciaría el server (es preferible, si es producción podrías obviar este paso) y luego intentar agregar los roles correspondientes.

¿Me imagino que están utilizando SignalR para trabajar con WebSockets?

Comment: No trabajo con SignalR. El problema que tengo es que cuando en la barra de navegador pongo "localhost" no me sale la pantalla web del IIS sino este error. He intentado remover IIS para volver a instalar pero como comento no me deja no se porque. El IIS que tengo es el 8.5 pero he leído que el WebSocket tiene que estar a true o false en el IIS, pero como también comentaba cuando voy a "Editor configuración" de IIS no sale la opción system.webServer/websocket. En otro servidor de IIS 8.5 que tengo funciona bien y si que aperece esta opción.

Comment: Entiendo, otra posible solución para remover el IIS e intentar hacer una instalación nuevamente para ver si se corrige este error, sería hacer la desinstalación utilizado Power Shell. desde este link puedes ver los comandos que se necesitan: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/vault-products/learn-explore/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-manually-remove-IIS-and-reinstall-it-in-Windows-2012-using-Powershell-Scripts.html

Comment: Al final lo he solucionado desinstalando desde PowerShell solo la parte de WebSockets con el comando "Remove-WindowsFeature -name Web-WebSockets"

Comment: Excelente escuchar esto :)